# Python Pandas Adding or Subtracting User Defined Numbers to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition, subtraction

I am trying to modify a dataframe that i am reading from an excel. I want to modify the columns 'Region1' and 'Region2', more specifically i want to subtract a user-defined number from 'Region1' column and add a user-defined number to 'Region2'. Can i modify the dataframe so that i can do both operations at the same time, i.e. subtract 5 from 'Region1' and add 5 to 'Region2'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\blahblah\\Desktop\\testroi.bed', delimiter= '\t')

df[['Region1', 'Region2']]

Region1 Region2
0   25870184    25870282
1   25880407    25880560
2   25881345    25881468
3   25883638    25883763
4   25889129    25889212
... ... ...
432 107645314   107645443
433 107646702   107646854
434 107651377   107651481
435 107651648   107651661
436 107665889   107665965
437 rows × 2 columns
```

I can create new dfs for 'Region1' and 'Region2' to do adding/subtracting, but i am wondering if i can perform this two operation at the same time with 1 line of code on the same dataframe. So basically using the dataframe above, 0th index would be 25870184 - 5 = 25870179 for 'Region1' and 25870282 + 5 = 25870287 for 'Region2'. Repeat the operation from all columns and rows, i.e. i know i can do via `df=df['Region1'] -5` but i am wondering if i can do two operations at the same time i.e. `df = df['Region1'] -5 , df['Region2'] + 5`. The trouble i have is making two operations at the same time on the same data frame.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do both at the same time?

Comment: If i create seperate DFs for the plus and minus operation, i feel like i have to keep track of multiple DFs and merge them later which can be harder to maintain especially with big datasets. So i wanted to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (and fastest, as it is *inplace*) is:

```py
df[['Region1', 'Region2']] += [-5, 5]

>>> df[['Region1', 'Region2']]
       Region1    Region2
0     25870179   25870287
1     25880402   25880565
2     25881340   25881473
3     25883633   25883768
4     25889124   25889217
432  107645309  107645448
433  107646697  107646859
434  107651372  107651486
435  107651643  107651666
436  107665884  107665970
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify all values simultaneously using `apply`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], columns=["Region1", "Region2"])

   Region1  Region2
0        0        0
1        1        1
2        2        2

number1, number2 = 1, 2 # User defined numbers

def adjust(row):
    row["Region1"] -= number1
    row["Region2"] += number2
    return row

df.apply(adjust, axis=1)
```

Output

```
   Region1  Region2
0       -1        2
1        0        3
2        1        4
```

However, I don't see any advantage over simply doing 2 separate operations:

```
df["Region1"] -= number1
df["Region2"] += number2
df
```

Output:

```
   Region1  Region2
0       -1        2
1        0        3
2        1        4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) statement, as follows:

```
df = df.assign(Region1=(df['Region1'] - 5), Region2=(df['Region2'] + 5))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

       Region1    Region2
0     25870179   25870287
1     25880402   25880565
2     25881340   25881473
3     25883633   25883768
4     25889124   25889217
432  107645309  107645448
433  107646697  107646859
434  107651372  107651486
435  107651643  107651666
436  107665884  107665970
```

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for those quick & fantastic suggestions. I tried them and they all worked. I am a happy camper. :)

Comment: @Yeah thanks, i try to upvote answers but i don't have enough points. I am a peasent.

Comment: @MuffinManCaniko  You can still accept answer no matter how many points you have.  Accept not upvote.   I have already provided you with guideline [How to accept SO answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))

Comment: Ah sorry yes i got it now, shame i can only accept one.